# Magento 1.9 Admin Dashboard Won't Load

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

My Magento 1.9 Admin Dashboard won't load anything past the header... The customer facing side of the site seems to be working fine and I can login and log out of the Admin Panel, but I can't do much in the way of administration since none of the tabs will load.

There are no Javascript Errors in the Console, it just doesn't load.

[image]
[image]

I was trying to add a custom module without knowing what I was doing, so I'm pretty sure I'm the one who broke it, but I can't seem to find which file I messed up, let alone what part of it I messed up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure that your module is causing the problem, try disabling it from

```
app/etc/modules/VendorName_ModuleName.xml
```

inside the file put false where you can see `<active>true</active>`

Flush the cache and try.
If it's a your module's issue, try looking to the logs.

Comment: I think this might have been the problem... Or something like it, thought I'm not 100% sure. I was finally able to find and replace all of the files I'd edited with original versions from the stage server and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe due to the following reason

- The cookie domain in System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management doesn't match the actual site domain
- Incorrect permissions on var/session, preventing session files from being saved

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I came across this solution somewhere else and tried it, but it didn't seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually new extension/modules are the culprit in these cases.

As highlighted by alex, you can disable the newly added module and clear all cache to make it work.

Glad you got it resolved.